# Angular routing with parameter issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have MVC application, I want make routing for the following URL

```
http://localhost:2668/Home/User/1
```

I try

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
//here we will write code for implement routing 
$routeProvider
.when('#/Home/User/:userid', {
    templateUrl: '/AngularTemplates/User.html',
    controller: 'UserController'
})

.otherwise({   // This is when any route not matched
    controller: 'ErrorController'
}) })
```

And then the `UserController` as below:

```
.controller('UserController', ['$scope','$routeParams', function ($scope,$routeParams) {
    // $routeParams used for get query string value

    //var loc = window.location.href;
    //var id = loc.slice(loc.lastIndexOf('/'), loc.length).split('/')[1];
    $scope.Message = "This is ORDER Page with query string id value =" + $routeParams.userid;
}])
```

But I always get "undefined" for the para `$routeParams.userid`

What is wrong in my code? Please help thanks!

Comment: Just remove # from the when condition.You doesnt need it.

Comment: Thanks but it still "undefined".

Comment: :userid} should be :userid Have a look at "}".

Comment: Thanks I just remove it but it still not works correct. Maybe duplicate with MVC routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <a href="/Home/User/11">user 11</a>
    <a href="/Home/User/12">user 12</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

      app.config([
          '$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
          function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

              $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                  enabled: true,
                  requireBase: false
              }).hashPrefix('!');

              $routeProvider
                .when('/Home/User/:userid', {
                    template: '<pre>{{ message }}</pre>',
                    controller: 'UserController'
              });
          }]);

      app.controller('UserController', ['$scope','$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
          $scope.message = "userid = " + $routeParams.userid;
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JSBin http://output.jsbin.com/geluli

You may read more about default router here (nice examples + tests) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: Nice! But `.hashPrefix('!')` is not really required?!